# Using SSIS to connect to Google API Sheets V4

Tags: ssis, google-sheets-api

I am trying to connect to an Excel spreadsheet published in Google and download its data to SQL using SQL Server Information Services (SSIS).

I am following the example posted by google for .net https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/dotnet
Everything went well in my Visual Studio SSDT environment. I connect and download the data correctly.

When I publish the package in the information services catalog it doesn't work. It doesn't give an error, it just keeps running. I can not find any log or any indication that tells me where to look for the fault.

Comment: If you run an execution report from the catalog what does it say? How long are you letting it run before killing the job?

Comment: Hello. It was running for hours. The package report says that it validates correctly but does not execute it.

Comment: Mi error. tenia una linea de codigo erronea -Console.ReadLine() y el packete esperaba un caracter de entrada. Riesgos de copiar y pegar codigo sin revisar bien. Muchas gracias por contestar.

Saludos